# What is the difference between the kernel parameters in output of sysctl -a and the kernel settings in /boot/config-kernel-version?

Tags: linux, kernel

What is the difference between the kernel parameters from the output of sysctl -a and the kernel configuration settings from the file
/boot/config-kernel-version?

Comment: Useful question: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/761663/what-if-kernel-parameter-conflicted-in-grub-and-sysctl

Answer (score 1):

The settings in `/boot/config-...` reflect the configuration settings with which the kernel was built; most of them can’t be modified at runtime. (Those that can, can’t be modified by editing `/boot/config-...`, but *via* other means, such as `sysctl`.)

The settings shown by `sysctl -a` are runtime settings, exposed under `/proc/sys`; most of them are modifiable at runtime. They are described [in the kernel documentation](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/admin-guide/sysctl/).

Comment: So we can say that in this case and generally 'kernel-parameters' and 'kernel-settings' are one and the same thing, can we?

Comment: I wouldn’t; IMO it’s important to distinguish between compile-time settings and runtime settings...

Comment: what exactly should we understand under 'runtime'? the time when the os is booting or something else?

Comment: By “runtime settings” I mean settings which can be changed while the kernel is running, as opposed to settings which are compiled in to the kernel.

Comment: Why does `/boot/config-...` exist if the settings are compiled into the kernel? Is it just for reference?

Comment: @glibg10b yes, it’s just for reference. The kernel doesn’t use the file at all.