# What if kernel parameter conflicted in grub and sysctl?

Tags: boot, grub, sysctl

For example, if I set `oops=panic` in grub command and I also set `kernel.panic_on_oops=0` in sysctl config? ex: in /etc/sysctl.d/

What would happen?

Are these two parameters mapping to the same function/feature in the kernel?

Why not use the same variable name?

Comment: No idea about their relationship but sysctl.d should override things set in the kernel command line since it is processed later.

Comment: (Assuming it is processed at all, since `oops=panic` might trigger a panic before the system ever gets to applying sysctl settings)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sysctl` settings are applied after boot, so in most cases they override equivalent settings given on the kernel command-line (the exceptions are values which can only be set once).

Both the kernel `oops` argument and the `kernel.panic_on_oops` sysctl map to the same variable, [`panic_on_oops`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v6.6.1/source/kernel/panic.c#L54). This is set by [`oops_setup`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v6.6.1/source/kernel/panic.c#L773) if a value is specified on the command-line, and [is exported *via* sysctl in the `kernel` table](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v6.6.1/source/kernel/sysctl.c#L1823).

[The variable definition](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v6.6.1/source/kernel/panic.c#L54) shows a *third* way of setting it: its default value is controlled by a [build configuration setting, `CONFIG_PANIC_ON_OOPS`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v6.6.1/source/lib/Kconfig.debug#L982).

As for why the same name isn’t used, there are probably historical reasons, and there remains one significant difference: `panic_on_oops` expects 0 or 1, whereas `oops` looks for a value matching “panic”; so while both settings map to the same underlying variable, `oops` adds a level of indirection.